# how to join 2 tables based on array condition contains

Tags: google-bigquery

I have 2 tables:

Product Table contains productTitle [string] column
[image: Product Table]

keyword mapping table contains 2 columns, category [string] and keyword [repeated record - string]

Note: keywords are mutually exclusive: regexp_contains(keyword) uniquely assigns you to 1 specific cat_id

[image]

**my Goal**: merge the 2 table so that I have cat_id for each ProdTitle

Join Logic: if the keyword (case insensitive) is contained prodTitle then assign the category_id to prodTitle

how would you do this in an efficient manner?

Comment: and what logic for such merge you have in mind? please elaborate

Comment: question updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have a single row for each product, I grouped it by productId and productTitle.
If you don't want to use group by, you can just delete it and change `ARRAY_AGG(cat_id)` to plain `cat_id`.
So, I think you can use this one.

```
WITH 
products AS (
  SELECT 1 productId, 'lorem ipsum cat1 lorem ipsum' as productTitle union all
  SELECT 2 productId, 'lorem ipsum cat2 lorem ipsum' as productTitle union all
  SELECT 3 productId, 'lorem ipsum cat3 lorem ipsum' as productTitle union all
  SELECT 4 productId, 'lorem ipsum cat4 lorem ipsum' as productTitle
),
categories AS (
  SELECT 1 as cat_id, ['cat1', 'something', 'else'] as keywords union all
  SELECT 2 as cat_id, ['cat2', 'another', 'keyword'] as keywords
)
select productId, productTitle, ARRAY_AGG(cat_id) categories
from products p
cross join categories c
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(c.keywords) as k WHERE p.productTitle LIKE CONCAT('%', k, '%'))
GROUP BY 1,2
```